# Image from Open Graph is not appearing in Telegram/Viber

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, telegram, viber

The last few days I have been trying to figure out why Telegram and Viber do not display the og:image from the canonical url of the site. If I insert a link in the messenger with any get parameter, like https://example.com/?t=2 everything will work. Without it - no. This occurs only in Telegram and Viber, Instagram and Facebook always display an image, regardless of the type of link.
Here is my metatags setup:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{my_png_image_direct_url}" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{my_png_image_direct_url}" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="968" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="504" />
<meta property="og:title" content="..." />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="...." />
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="uk_UA" />
```

Comment: Does Telegram and Viber support Open Graph? If not is it expected.

Comment: To cover @WizKid question, [Telegram](https://telegram.me/s/ProgrammingTip?q=open+graph) says they use the Open Graph protocol, specifically the title, type, image, and URL to create rich link previews. As to no image, I’ve seen it [before](https://www.baltimoresun.com/sports/ravens/bs-sp-ravens-wormley-defense-49ers-20191202-6ydswktd5vgdnflyzdcuwhjlri-story.html), but I don’t know what causes it. Telegram does have a bot for updating links [@WebPageBot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot) – if you can rescan your page, it might pick up your image. I don't know about Viber – I've never used it.

Answer (score 12):

**Explanation**
If you change the domain or something else regarding DNS on where the preview image is hosted, Telegram might have cached the link which is used for displaying the preview of your site.

This causes the image to not load in correctly. I guess Telegram then tries to load the image from the old URL.

**✅ Solution**
You can use Telegram's [@webpagebot](https://telegram.me/webpagebot) to update the link preview of your site. Just start the chat and send it the link to your website.

**The image should now be displayed correctly!**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, Viber does not support the `http` protocol for Open Graph images. Only `https`.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out telegram doesn't like `.webp` and `.avif` formats (see [this github issue](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/16312)).

So I just replaced my image with `.jpeg` and used [@webpagebot](https://t.me/webpagebot) to quickly update the link.